# unable to build the nosqlunit-mongodb project

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I am unable to build the nosqlunit-mongodb project. Compiling the project is giving me below exception. Please help me in understanding what is this exception about and how to overcome the same.

Just getting started with nosqlunit and mongodb. Please bear with me for my naive question.

```
user@host:nosqlunit-mongodb mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building nosqlunit-mongodb 0.7.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: <http s>:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit-core/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to sonatype-nexus-snapshots (http s:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from https:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of sonatype-nexus-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
Downloading: http s:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit-core/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/nosqlunit-core-0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
Downloading: http s:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/lordofthejars/nosqlunit-mongodb/0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-mongodb:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to sonatype-nexus-snapshots (http s:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.360s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 10 06:17:30 PST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 140M/698M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project nosqlunit-mongodb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-mongodb:jar:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:jar:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:2.7.3 (compile), com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-mongodb:jar:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT (compile), jmockmongo:jmockmongo:jar:0.0.2 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.11 (provided), org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3 (compile), org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3 (compile), org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.0 (test), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:jar:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:pom:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT from/to sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https:/oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] htt p: /cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compile only nosqlunit-mongodb, so Maven tries to retrieve *com.lordofthejars:nosqlunit-core:jar:0.7.1-SNAPSHOT* from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 but it doesn't exists there.

Run **mvn compile** in the project root directory to compile all the modules (included nosqlunit-core) and it should work.